# How do you tell if witness data has been tampered with?

Tags: segregated-witness

If you receive a block, how can you tell whether the witness data has been tampered with between when it was mined and when you received it?

Where in the block is the `wtxid` root, and how do you compute the merkle root of the witness data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quoting from [BIP141](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0141.mediawiki):

> The commitment is recorded in a scriptPubKey of the coinbase transaction.

and

> A witness root hash is calculated with all those wtxid as leaves, in a way similar to the hashMerkleRoot in the block header.

Indeed, the witness merkle root seems to [be computed](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/57b34599b2deb179ff1bd97ffeab91ec9f904d85/src/consensus/merkle.cpp#L168) in a similar way than the hash merkle root, since it calls [the same function](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/57b34599b2deb179ff1bd97ffeab91ec9f904d85/src/consensus/merkle.cpp#L133).

I guess you can just check if the witness data has been tampered with by just computing the witness root hash yourself and checking that it matches the stored one.